# Angular: map string array to array of enum values in http get call

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, enums, type-conversion

I have an enumeration in my typescript code, which lists all possible user roles:

```
enum UserRole {
    CONSULTANT,
    MANAGER,
    ...
}
```

And I have a REST endpoint `/users/id/roles` that returns array of strings representing roles of a particular user:

```
[
    "CONSULTANT",
    "MANAGER",
    ...
]
```

Now I want to map this array in my frontend code. I tied doing it like this:

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from "rxjs/Observable";
import {plainToClass} from "class-transformer";
...

getUserRoles(id: string): Observable<UserRole[]> {
    return this.http.get(`/users/${id}/roles`)
        .map(responce => plainToClass(UserRole, responce.json()));
}
```

But I get:

> error TS2345: Argument of type 'typeof UserRole' is not assignable to parameter of type 'ClassType'.
>     Type 'typeof UserRole' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any[]): UserRole[]'.

**Q:** Is there any way to convert string-array to array of enum elements?

**Note:** Im using Typescript 2.5.3. in pair with Angular 5.0.5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map` on the array returned from your server, once you've converted it to an object using `json`, like so:

```
return this.http.get(`/users/${id}/roles`)
    .map(response => response.json().map(x => UserRole[x]));
}
```

In case you get a Typescript error, you might need to cast the `json` result first, like so:

```
return this.http.get(`/users/${id}/roles`)
    .map(response => (<string[]>response.json()).map(x => UserRole[x]));
}
```